# How to customize ConstraintProvider in OptaPlanner?

Tags: optaplanner

This is a shift scheduling application. I'm already dynamically control some of the constraints on/off by changing weight, which is great. And some specific constraints can already be dynamically controlled with the planning object properties (Employee's contract maximum). I still haven't found a way to make the ConstraintProvider parametrized based on configuration. My question is:

Can a ConstraintProvider be programmatically created, instead of defining in the solverConfig.xml? So I can inject my own parameters

I would want this constraint to be dyniamically adjusted with not just 10 hours fixed duration (that 10 * 60 hardcoded value):

```java
Constraint breakBetweenNonConsecutiveShiftsIsAtLeastTenHours(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return getAssignedShiftConstraintStream(constraintFactory)
                .join(Shift.class,
                      equal(Shift::getEmployee),
                      lessThan(Shift::getEndDateTime, Shift::getStartDateTime))
                .filter((s1, s2) -> !Objects.equals(s1, s2))
                .filter((s1, s2) -> s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.HOURS) < 10)
                .penalizeConfigurableLong(CONSTRAINT_BREAK_BETWEEN_NON_CONSECUTIVE_SHIFTS, (s1, s2) -> {
                    long breakLength = s1.getEndDateTime().until(s2.getStartDateTime(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
                    return (10 * 60) - breakLength;
                });
    }
```

(I could add a field on Shift to return the same values for all shifts, but that's messy).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the best way is to create a custom class to store the duration (ex: MinimumBreakBetweenNonConsecutiveShifts) add it as a field to Roster, and annotate the field with `@ProblemFact`. Then you can join the stream with the problem fact with `constraintFactory.from(...).join(MinimumBreakBetweenNonConsecutiveShifts.class)` We are currently discussing alternative methods for access to problem facts here: https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232679-optaplanner/topic/Constraint.20context

(https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/issues/502#issuecomment-701479372)

Answer (score 0):

What is also possible is to expose parameters as functions in the constraint provider implementation and later inherit the base constraint provider impl to override the respective parameters

```
 open class MyConstraintsProvider : ConstraintProvider{
    open fun doAvoidOverlap()  = true
 }


 // parameterized version
 class CustomProvider : MyConstraintsProvider() {
    override fun doAvoidOverlap() = false
 }

 // instantiate the solver  
SolverConfig()
  .withConstraintProviderClass(CustomProvider::class.java)
```

However to make this truly configurable (e.g. from a config file), we need to resort to the jsr223 scripting compiler because optaplanner does only support zero argument constructors. See https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C7L3JB43G/p1661783750781029 for an example (which was motivated from optaplanner but abstracted for kotlin-slack).

The above mentioned approach could be adjusted to plain java as well.